# appending a collections object

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I am working on an existing application that is a package tracking application and I want to append a collections list object.

My code is:

```
public class VehicleAssignElement
{
    public VehicleAssignElement(string pkgID, string DriverID, string VehicleID)
    {
        pkgID = ConfID;
        DriverID = puID;
        VehicleID = doID;
    }

    public string pkgID { get; set; }
    public string DriverID { get; set; }
    public string VehicleID { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleAssignID
{
    public List<VehicleAssignElement> AssignID { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleAssignIDList
{
    public List<VehicleAssignID> AssignRecord { get; set; }
}
```

I have a code block where I loop through to get the pkgID.

```
assignElement.AssignID.Add( new VehicleAssignElement(oPackageTracking.pkgID,"",""));
```

I have another code block that I need to loop through to get the DriverID and a 3rd code block to loop the get the VehicleID.

**Question**:
How would I go about appending the collection to add DriverID as the second element and the VehicleID as the 3rd element?
Using `assignElement.AssignID.Add` but that adds to the collection. I tried Insert, but was unsuccessful as well.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You can't add strings `DriverID` or `VehicleID` as elements in a `Collection` that accepts `VehicleAssignElement` objects. This whole approach needs reworking. Why not just add `VehicleAssignElement` objects to the collection, then `get` their `DriverID` or `VehicleID` fields as needed?

Comment: Where does the `AssignID` come from? Also you name a property `pkgID` and a parameter of the contructor `pkgID`.

Comment: Can you show an example? I am new to the world of collections.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant something like this:

```
public class VehicleAssignElement
{
    public VehicleAssignElement(string pkgID, string driverID, string vehicleID)
    {
        this.PkgID = pkgID;
        this.DriverID = driverID;
        this.VehicleID = vehicleID;
    }

    public string PkgID { get; set; }
    public string DriverID { get; set; }
    public string VehicleID { get; set; }
}  


public class Form1 : Form
{

    private List<VehicleAssignElement> _assignmentList = new List<VehicleAssignElement>();

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        VehicleAssignElement assignment1 = new VehicleAssignElement("pkg1", "John", "Audi");
        _assignmentList.Add(assignment1);

        VehicleAssignElement assignment2 = new VehicleAssignElement("pkg2", "Morgan", "Volkswagen");
        _assignmentList.Add(assignment2);

        foreach(var assignment in _assignmentList)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} -> {1} - {2}", assignment.PkgID, assignment.DriverID, assignment.VehicleID));
        }
    }
}
```

NOT TESTED. So it may contain some syntax errors.. But this is for example.

Comment: wow..very interesting. and simple. I will try this out and let you know. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: actually this may not work. Because after getting the pkgID, the app goes out of scope of the class file to another class to get parameters, then goes to another class to get the list of drivers. That collection is what I am looking to add to this collection. Hope that is making sense. So I guess I would need a global object to store the values.

Comment: As long the a Form1 instance lives, the _assignmentList lives. And when a VehicleAssignElement is added to the _assignmentList, it will stay alive. The out of scope rule only applies when there are no references left.